# How can I use SVNLook functionality on client machine

Tags: svn, msbuild, teamcity

All

I wish to call the svnlook commandline from my MSbuild script using the Exec command, however all the documentation I have read seems to indicate that this can only be run on the machine holding the repository itself (i.e. the server.)

Does anyone know how I can access this functionality from the client machine, is there a client wrapper for calling this functionality (i.e. a combination of svn log & svn info)??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

svnlook works directly on the repository database. That database is not available on the client computer (usually, unless you access the repository via file:///). So there's no way to use svnlook.

You can get most information with the svn client.

you didn't mention what information you want exactly, but I suggest using

```
svn log
svn diff
svn info
```

Answer (score 2):

svn log -rev 'head' -v url

this shows similar  dirs_changed from svnlook

Answer (score 0):

```
svn merge –dry-run -r BASE:HEAD .
```

Answer (score 0):

I use simple script `svn-report.sh` for getting changes for interval of revisions (running script without parameters returns latest revison):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reports SVN commits from version (parameter1) to version (parameter2)

if [ "$#" = "2" ]; then
    echo "SVN commits for versions" $1 "till" $2
    for (( i=$1; i<=$2; i++ ))
    do
        svn log -r $i -v
        echo ""
    done
else
    echo "Usage: svn-report [from earlier revision number] [to latest revison number]"
    echo "Example: ./svn-report.sh 30 35"
    echo "Latest revison is:"
    svn log -r head
fi
```